# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in ubuntu terminal

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal, cron

I am crating a cron scheduler for which i am using the following code:-

```
import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.ScheduleBuilder;

public class CronSched {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException {
    System.out.println("Started");
    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(CronJob.class).build();
    Trigger t1 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("MAILER").withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 33 2 1/1 * ? *")).build();
    Scheduler sc = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

    sc.start();
    sc.scheduleJob(job,t1);
  }

}
```

and I am compiling teh following code in terminal with the following statement:-

```
javac -cp ".:/home/aditya/CronSched/lib/quartz-2.2.3.jar: /home/aditya/CronSched/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar: /home/aditya/CronSched/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar: " CronSched.java
```

and on running the code I am using the following statement:-

```
java CronSched
```

and I am getting the following error:-

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/ScheduleBuilder
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.ScheduleBuilder
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

What to Do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add all necessaries jars to your runtime classpath.

```
java -cp "quartz-2.2.3.jar:...." CronSched
```

Comment: during execution also?

Comment: yes, during execution. otherwise you could build a "fat"-jar with all necessaries classes and then you could run the jar with java -jar fat.jar

Comment: great it worked! but another error occured    java -cp ".:/home/aditya/CronSched/lib/quartz-2.2.3.jar: /home/aditya/CronSched/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar: /home/aditya/CronSched/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar: /home/aditya/CronSched/lib/slf-log.jar: /home/aditya/CronSched/lib/slf-jdk.jar " CronSched
Started
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory